# BARON ERROR: can’t open nl file when using JuMP in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

I was trying to use BARON to solve some problems.

JuMP.jl version: 0.21.5

BARON.jl version: 0.6.5

When I run my program, the following error occurs:

```
C:\Program Files\ampl_mswin64\baron.exe: can't open C:\Users\Lujia\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_1V2Lgu\baron_problem.bar.nl
ERROR: LoadError: failed process: Process(`'C:\Program Files\ampl_mswin64\baron.exe' 'C:\Users\Lujia\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_1V2Lgu\baron_problem.bar'`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]
```

It seems the baron executable cannot find a .nl file. How can I solve that issue?

I do see C:\Users\Lujia\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_1V2Lgu\baron_problem.bar exists when using debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a link when posting in multiple locations:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/baron-error-cant-open-nl-file/48456. I would prefer we continued any discussion on the Julia forum.